# Recreating CloudFormation Build Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Created a CloudFormation stack template named foo.yaml. I validate, package, and deploy a stack from foo.yaml:

```
aws cloudformation package `
--template-file .\foo.yaml`
--s3-bucket abc123 `
--output-template-file .\foo.pkg.yaml

$parameters = ...

aws cloudformation deploy `
--template-file .\foo.pkg.yaml `
--stack-name foo `
--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM `
--s3-bucket abc123 `
--parameter-overrides $parameters
```

I then delete the S3 bucket used in that deployment. Is there a way I can regenerate that bucket from CloudFormation?

P.S. I realize I can create the bucket and populate it manually, but I'm asking if there is anything automatic.

Comment: For folks that stumbled across this question in pursuit of an answer, I've found the answer to be no. If you accidentally delete your build bucket you have to manually create the bucket with the same name and add objects from the package process to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a button or option to re-populate an S3 bucket with objects created when a stack's template was packaged.

You can ONLY do this manually:

1. Find the CF stack instance's template
2. Locate the bucket name from the template
3. Create a new S3 bucket with the same name
4. Re-package your CF stack template adding the bucket name from step-3 to the `aws cloudformation package` command:

   aws cloudformation package --s3-bucket

Bucket recreated w/artifacts!

Comment: Okay. So, question answered; no option to re-populate bucket. I was just afraid I wouldn't have a local copy of the stack's template w/accompanying scripts to recreate the bucket like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if the bucket can be created automatically from a CloudFormation command, then it's not really possible. You can create a S3 Bucket Resource ofcourse as a part of a Stack Resource.

I believe it is simpler to create the Bucket manually.

Comment: I’m not as concerned with the mechanics of creating the bucket as regenerating the stuff that should’ve been in the bucket.